# Format line in ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` to display user informations. Here can you see the content from the list:

```js
String[] userAttributes = new String[] {
        "Username:            " + username,
        "Vorname:              " + userVorname,
        "Name:                    " + userName,
        "Geburtsdatum:    " + userGebdat,
        "Adresse",
        "Straße:                   " + userStrasse,
        "Hausnr:                  " +userHausnr,
        "Ort:                          " +userOrt,
        "Postleitzahl:          " +userPlz,
        "Einsatzdaten",
        "Einsatzort:             "+ userEinsatzort,
        "Einsatzland:          "+userEinsatzland,
        "Kontaktmöglichkeiten",
        "Skype:                     "+userSkype,
        "Handynr:                "+userHandynr,
        "E-Mail:                    " +userEmail,

};
```

No I want to format the following lines in this ListView:

- Adresse
- Einsatzdaten
- Kontaktmöglichkeiten

This is my activity:

```js
public class BenutzerOverviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView userListView ;
    private String username;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> userListViewAdapter;
    private String berechtigung;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_benutzer_overview);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Bundle intentExtras = getIntent().getExtras();
        username = intentExtras.getString("username");
        String userVorname = intentExtras.getString("userVorname");
        String userName = intentExtras.getString("userName");
        String userGebdat = intentExtras.getString("userGebdat");
        String userStrasse = intentExtras.getString("userStrasse");
        String userHausnr = intentExtras.getString("userHausnr");
        String userOrt = intentExtras.getString("userOrt");
        String userPlz = intentExtras.getString("userPlz");
        String userEinsatzort = intentExtras.getString("userEinsatzort");
        String userEinsatzland = intentExtras.getString("userEinsatzland");
        String userSkype = intentExtras.getString("userSkype");
        String userHandynr = intentExtras.getString("userHandynr");
        String userEmail = intentExtras.getString("userEmail");

        setTitle(userVorname + " " + userName);

        // Get user permission
        SharedPreferences loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences("userData", MODE_PRIVATE);
        berechtigung = loginPreferences.getString("berechtigung", "Fehler");

        // Find the ListView resource.
        userListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.userListView);

        // Create and populate a List of user attributes.
        String[] userAttributes = new String[] {
                "Username:            " + username,
                "Vorname:              " + userVorname,
                "Name:                    " + userName,
                "Geburtsdatum:    " + userGebdat,
                "Adresse",
                "Straße:                   " + userStrasse,
                "Hausnr:                  " +userHausnr,
                "Ort:                          " +userOrt,
                "Postleitzahl:          " +userPlz,
                "Einsatzdaten",
                "Einsatzort:             "+ userEinsatzort,
                "Einsatzland:          "+userEinsatzland,
                "Kontaktmöglichkeiten",
                "Skype:                     "+userSkype,
                "Handynr:                "+userHandynr,
                "E-Mail:                    " +userEmail,

        };

        ArrayList<String> userAttributesList = new ArrayList<>();
        userAttributesList.addAll(Arrays.asList(userAttributes));

        // Create ArrayAdapter using the userAttributesList.
        userListViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.user_listview_row, userAttributesList);

        // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.
        userListView.setAdapter(userListViewAdapter);

    }

    //Fragment XML geben, sowie als Menü setzen
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if(berechtigung.equalsIgnoreCase("Administrator")) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_benutzer_overview, menu);
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_editbutton) {

        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_deletebutton) {
            // OnCLickListener for an event
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {

                        // Case user types Yes
                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:

                           
                            // Exit case button positive/yes
                            break;

                        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                            // Dismiss dialog
                            dialog.dismiss();

                            // Exit case button negative/no
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };
            // AlertDialog for logout check
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.deleteAlert))
                    .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes), dialogClickListener)
                    .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no), dialogClickListener)
                    .show();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I want to underline it and change the color for this three "headlines". How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a CustomAdapter.

In your activity or fragment create the adapter using

```
public class YourActivty extends Activity {
   private CustomAdapter<String> userListViewAdapter;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    userListViewAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, Arrays.asList(userAttributes));
    listview.setAdapter(userListViewAdapter);
  }

  class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdaptery<String> { 

   private Context context;
   private String[] data;
   private String TAG = "BulsListAdapter";

   public CustomAdapter (Context context, String[] data) {
        super(context, R.layout.your_list_item, data);
        this.context = context;
        this.data= data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_list_item, parent, false);
        }

        final TextView textViewInItem = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewInItem );

      String myData = data[position];
      if (myData.startsWith("Adresse") || myData.startsWith("Einsatzdaten") || myData.startsWith("Kontaktmöglichkeiten")) {
       textViewInItem.setColor(...);
       SpannableString content = new SpannableString(myData);
       content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
       textViewInItem.setText(content);

      } else {
       textViewInItem.setText(myData);
      }
   return convertView;
   }
 } 
}
```

And of course create a new class with the Adapter or include it into your existing Class.

Comment: I have added my adapter in question because it's a little bit different to your solution. How can I do this with my adapter solution? Thanks :) Btw I've made my adapter direclty in my Activity without any additional class

Comment: updated. Of course you can use other solutions aswell, but this is a quick and simple solution.

Comment: return statement missing

Comment: And I think this isn't working for my activity :/. I've added my whole activity for you

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution and works perfectly!!

```js
// Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.
userListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.user_listview_row, userAttributesList) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView userListView_row = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        if (userListView_row.getText().toString().equals("Adresse") || userListView_row.getText().toString().equals("Einsatzdaten") || userListView_row.getText().toString().equals("Kontaktmöglichkeiten") || userListView_row.getText().toString().equals("Benutzerdaten")) {
            // Underline string
            SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(userListView_row.getText().toString());
            spannableString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, userListView_row.length(), 0);
            userListView_row.setText(spannableString);

            // Change string color
            userListView_row.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

            // Set text size
            userListView_row.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);

        } else {
            // Change string color
            userListView_row.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGrey));

            // Set text size
            userListView_row.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
        }

        return userListView_row;
    }
});
```